# Unable to use the data sent to the server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

This is my express server

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require("dotenv").config();
const cors = require("cors");
const userData = require("./db");
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://localhost", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to database!!");
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log("Error : " + err);
  });

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ server: "Running" });
});
app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ user: "true" });
});

app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req);
  res.redirect("/");
});
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

and this is my React component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Signup.css";
import axios from "axios";

import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectAuth } from "../../features/authSlice";
export default function Login() {
  const isAuthenticated = useSelector(selectAuth);
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");
  const [pass, setPass] = useState("");

  const handleSignup = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var bodyFormData = new FormData();
    bodyFormData.append("username", user);
    bodyFormData.append("password", pass);
    const res = await axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "http://localhost:3001/signup",
      data: bodyFormData,
      headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="signup__container">
      <h2>Signup</h2>
      <form className="signup__form" autoComplete="off">
        <div className="signup__imgContainer">
          <img
            src={require("../../assets/avatar-placeholder.jpg").default}
            alt="Avatar"
            className="signup__avatar"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="signup__inputContainer">
          <label for="uname">
            <b>Username</b>
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter Username"
            name="uname"
            onChange={(e) => setUser(e.target.value)}
            required
          />

          <label for="psw">
            <b>Password</b>
          </label>
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Enter Password"
            name="psw"
            required
            onChange={(e) => setPass(e.target.value)}
          />

          <button type="submit" onClick={handleSignup}>
            Signup
          </button>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" /> Remember me
          </label>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div>{isAuthenticated.toString()}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am trying to post data using axios but I am unable to access this data in my backend. Am i doing it right, if yes then can anyone tell me what's wrong. and if no then how can I correct it to use the data.
I tried various things like sending the data as params but nothing worked on server it was always undefined however the `console.log(req)` gives something but I didn't see any of my post data in it.

Comment: remove the the type="submit" from the button prop .

Comment: In case that doesn't work,you might have to use bodyParser module.

Comment: nothing worked. tried removing type="submit" and also the bodyParser module is not working and the bodyParser shows deprecated

Answer (score 0):

add app.use(express.json());
if it does not work. then add body-parser in your package.

```html
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser"); // install body-parser
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

 
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50mb" }));
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    limit: "50mb",
    extended: true,
    parameterLimit: 50000,
  })
);
app.use(express.json()); /// add
```

Comment: This is also not working i did
  `console.log(req.username);
  console.log(req.params.username);
 console.log(req.query.username);
  console.log(req.body.username);`

  to see if i can access but it is undefinded.

Comment: pass the data as string  , data: JSON.stringify(bodyFormData)

Comment: I tried something else and it works 
`axios({method: "post",url: `http://localhost:3001/login/?username=${user}&password=${pass}`,})`

Comment: I think you getting it from params, and not from the body

Comment: you should try ,data: JSON.stringify(bodyFormData)

Answer (score 0):

In the React app, you're using Content-Type `multipart/form-data`. When you use this Content-Type, the server needs to parse the request differently. This Content-Type is used when you want to upload a file in the request. It isn't the case here, so you should use Content-Type `application/json` instead.

Your request should be:

```
 const res = await axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "http://localhost:3001/signup",
      data: { username : user, password : pass},
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json },
    });
```

And in the Express application, you need to add a middleware to parse incoming requests in application/json Content-Type.

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json()); // <---- add this
```

In the route, you can see the data inside `req.body`

```
app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.redirect("/");
});
```